# Sumar un valor independiente a las tuplas / rows en base de datos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Si tengo un `select * from personas` que retorna lo siguiente:

```
   Nombre   | Valor
   ----------------- 
    Carlos  |   10
   ----------------- 
    Miguel  |   20
```

¿Puedo en mi consulta sumar un valor especifico -*que se pueda obtener mediante sub-consultas*- para cada tupla?

```
    Nombre  | Valor
   ----------------- 
    Carlos  |   10 (+5 #Este numero se trae de una sub-consulta)
   ----------------- 
    Miguel  |   20 (+10, #Este numero se trae de una sub-consulta)
```

Lo que quiero es obtener lo siguiente:

```
Nombre  | Valor
   ----------------- 
    Carlos  |   15
   ----------------- 
    Miguel  |   30
```

Comment: Sí, se puede. Pero dinos algo más sobre tu modelo de datos: ¿De dónde salen esos +5 y +10? ¿Cuál es su SGBD? ¿MySQL?

Comment: Está todo especificado en la descripción de la pregunta.

Comment: Ok, veo que has modificado las etiquetas, perfecto. Te lo pregunto de otra forma: ¿a través de qué subconsultas has obtenido esos +5 y +10?

Comment: ¿Y si haces un join a las subconsultas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede utilizar `+ (valor)` luego del nombre de la columna para sumar el respectivo valor.

> Esto solo funciona para columnas numéricas, si la columna es un string u otro tipo, procure utilizar alguna función que permita castear el valor a uno numérico.

Si está trabajando con columnas agrupadas puede utilizar el `+ (valor)` dentro de funciones agregadas teniendo en consideración lo mencionado arriba.

```
sum(campo + 50)
```

Esto sumará `+50` por cada tupla / row que se haya agrupado.

Answer (score 1):

Si podría hacerlo directamente:

```
 select t01.valor + (select t02.valor2 from tabla t02 where condicon) as total
 from tabla_nombre t01
```

Comment: También podría ser con un join, dependiendo de la subconsulta.